# How to distinguish between UITableView custom section click and section first row click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`UITableView` returns the same callback "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`" with the same `NSIndexPath` (0,0) both for section click and section first row click. I'm using custom view for section header view and I need to perform some action on these section rows. Tried checking cell class with `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` but it's obviously returning the same row cell instead of section cell. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE** I could add my custom section view to first row instead of adding it as a section, however in that case, I would need to return different row height in "`heightForRowAtIndexPath`" and that would be not-performanc-wise decision.

**UPDATE** I'v designed my section view as a subclass of UITableViewCell, because I prefer to get native UITableView callbacks instead of workaround'ing with tap gestures or buttons.

Comment: I dont think the section header view is clickable

Comment: I mean if it's just a UIView without any clickable elements like buttons on it

Comment: @EricQian I have designed my section view as a subclass of UITableViewCell so believe me section is clickable and UITableView returns callback didSelect.

Comment: I have a UITableView with custom header view for my sections, but my tableview: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method is not called when I click on a header... The problem might come from somewhere else. Can you please post the code for your headerview customization?

Comment: add UITapgesture on your custom view of section. Will it not work?

Comment: You should not take header view as a subclass of UItableViewCell

Comment: Regarding to your updates, maybe by creating your header with a different identifier than the row cells, you could distinguish you headers by testing the identifier in the `tableview: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: @zbMax asking tableView for cellForRowAtIndexPath with index (0,0) always returns row cell not section cell, so identifier will be row cell identifier, not section cell

Comment: yes you're right. Can you let me know what do you want to do by clicking on a section header?

Comment: Probably the problem here is that the dataSource for the table does not reflect the number of the cells you're returning in the numberOfRowsInSection. Also i think that you can't get an indexPath of a section. If cells in the sections are different from the others, try by checking the class-type of the cell.

Comment: @zbMax When user clicks on section, I need to collapse/group rows of that section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centurion, if you want to have section that you open/close easily, I suggest you to use the class APLSectionHeaderView.
You can find more information on [APLSectionHeaderView.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/TVAnimationsGestures_APLSectionHeaderView_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139-TVAnimationsGestures_APLSectionHeaderView_h-DontLinkElementID_14) and [APLSectionHeaderView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/TVAnimationsGestures_APLSectionHeaderView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139-TVAnimationsGestures_APLSectionHeaderView_m-DontLinkElementID_15)

Hope it will help you.

I've been using it, so if you have some question about it...