# UITableView inside a Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

In my app I have a TableView that displays a list of Items. Tapping on any cell will expand it and will display information related to tapped item. I want to display the information in tabular form, will it be a good approach to have a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell?

Comment: I think this would not be a good idea due to performace issues (at least when it comes to scrolling that view). It maybe would be better to show a completely new screen with your tabular data on it.

Comment: But you could nontheless read this tutorial if you really want to do it: http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/

Comment: no this works fine and no performance issue but i have a large code but how i answer you

Comment: No You should better use a detailTableViewController for that instead of having a tableView in each cell

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting u to go for master-detail view controllers :) ,for your question "have a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell " for this u need to subclass the UITableviewCell and in that cell u put or add another tableview by managing datasource and delegate in custom cell see my answer it shows how to add tableview within the custom UITableView cell [see hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266838/in-table-view-how-to-add-another-custom-cell-in-expanded-cell-in-ios/18268048#18268048) and before that u hav to incerease the row height for each cell i did not included it, "one thing i created all programatically not used xib" :) hope u get some idea .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419787/how-to-distinguish-between-uitableview-custom-section-click-and-section-first-ro/17425195#17425195).

I think it is what you are looking for.